# cmake's ExternalProject_Add: how to set source, build and install directories

Tags: cmake, external-project

I want to use `ExternalProject_Add` function to install cmake enabled projects. I need to control the building and installation processes. More specifically, I want that cmake build and install in specific directories.

There is an option to select a path where to put the source directory: `SOURCE_DIR`. Is there something equivalent for `BUILD_DIR` and `INSTALL_DIR`? I did not see anything alike.

There is a `PREFIX` option:

> Root dir for entire project

What does it mean exactly? An how does cmake's ExternalProject_Add do the installation?

**Edit:**

This work, but I have no control over source directory and it does not install the library:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    wjelement-project

    GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/netmail-open/wjelement.git"
    GIT_TAG "v1.2"

    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    PATCH_COMMAND ""
    TEST_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""  

    #SOURCE_DIR "${MY_SOURCE_ROOT}/wjelement"
    BINARY_DIR "${MY_BUILD_DIR}/wjelement"
    INSTALL_DIR "${CCT_INSTALL_DIR}/wjelement"   
)
```

- If I uncomment `SOURCE_DIR`, it does not clone from `GIT_CLONE` but try to get source from `SOURCE_DIR` (and it fails because that's not what I expected...)
- If I comment `INSTALL_COMMAND  ""`, then it try to install in *C:/Program Files/wjelement*, the default (apparently) and not in `INSTALL_DIR`
- default path for source files seem to be `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/wjelement-project-prefix/src`

[Another Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29533159/what-is-install-dir-useful-for-in-externalproject-add-command) report *problem* (or at least non intuitive behavior) with `INSTALL_DIR`.

Comment: [Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html) describes both `BUILD_DIR` and `INSTALL_DIR` options. Also, here you may read about relation between `PREFIX` and default value for the options.

Comment: There is indeed an ````INSTALL_DIR````. I did not notice it. But there is no ````BUILD_DIR````. I think that ````BINARY_DIR```` is the command I am looking for.

Comment: Where could I read about relation between ````PREFIX```` and default value for the options?

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant `BINARY_DIR`. As for relations with `PREFIX`, there is line `INSTALL_DIR  = <prefix>`.

Comment: can't make it work with ````INSTALL_DIR```` and  ````SOURCE_DIR```` . I'll edit my question to add what I tried and what goes wrong.

Comment: First of all, which CMake version do you use? ExternalProject has different behavior for different versions.

Comment: CMAKE_VERSION = 3.6.2

Comment: `default path for source files seem ...` - This is referred as *DOWNLOAD_DIR* in documentation. From this directory `git clone` is executed. After the clone, subdirectory `wjelement` will contain sources, and referred as (default) *SOURCE_DIR*. So you observe exactly this behavior. As for `INSTALL_DIR` you found the proper question.